# Gradle toolVersion can't be used as a version of core plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I wanted to replace:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '7.3'
    ...config...
}
```

with:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'checkstyle' version '7.3'
    ...
}
checkstyle {
    ...config...
}
```

Why can't I do something like that?

Comment: "Because the tool is not designed that way" - what kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks you're interacting with are different.

In the first example, you're *applying* the checkstyle plugin, and in the second block you're configuring it.

In the second example, you're using the new plugins block (which requires an ID and in some cases, a version number).  This version number is ***not*** going to be the same as the configuration value for `toolVersion`.

I can't really find a version ID for checkstyle, so you can experiment with omitting the version (which does work for plugins like `'java'`, which are built-in), or stick with applying the plugin.  In the most general of cases, applying the plugin will still work in spite of the new plugin syntax.